# How can angular.js notify node.js to take an action?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean

I need to write an app using MEAN stack and I am totally new in web developement. The app consists of three files, namely server.js, index.html and controller.js. The plan is for a frontend user to click a button and the backend would go out to some site, grab the data and put the data in a mongodb. On my index.html, I have ng-click=goGetData and in controller.js I have the function $scope.goGetData() = function() {} but my problem is I do not know what to write in the function so that the controller.js can notify my server.js to get the data. I had considered using socket.io, but I thought it was overkill and I do not want to broadcast to every app when I just want the server.js to grab data? But what option do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to do it. All I need is to create a route with post and get.